# PHP MySQL find non matching records

Tags: php, mysql

Seems simple enough. I have 2 tables: MBR and MBR_new. I need to find each record in MBR that doesn't have a matching e-mail record in MBR_new.

```
$result = $db->query("
SELECT a.NICK
FROM MBR as a
LEFT JOIN   
MBR_new as b
ON b.email = a.EMAIL
WHERE b.email IS NULL;
");

while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {

    echo "No e-mail found for user $obj->NICK<br />";
}
```

This gives me no error but seems to go in an infinite loop. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not an infinite loop but two embedded table scans because you've not indexed the join column `email` in your MBR_new table.
Did you try your query with tables with very few test entries ?

If you don't have such index, using a `NOT IN(subquery)` will create a temporary and compact unique index for just the existing emails in the MBR_new table.

Also, don't you have emails in MBR_new that have the SAME email address multiple times (this could cause the join to explode.

Beware also of the datatype of the `email` column of table b : is it indexable in your installation (depends on your table storage format : is it a VARCHAR(n) with reasonnable limits ? is it the same type as in table a ?)

And how many times do you expect to see the same EMAIL address in your result set ? If it is just one time, then add "DISTINCT" to your selct, so that the query optimizer will immediately know that it can skip to the next distinct email in table a, and ignore further scannings of table b once it has found a match.

Beware also : are there null mail entries in tables A and B ? Wouldn't it be safe to first generate an table containing email addresses associated to a unique id, and then use this id only in tables A and B ? (outer joins on strings are really slow).

Comment: Correct. Indexing the email column in MBR_new did the trick, plus I had 4 duplicate entries as well.